# Some 2013 BH.SE Memes to Brighten Your Day

Tags: discussion

What's your favorite meme of 2013? Feel free to add more!

<sub>*I was asked to make each meme a separate post that can be voted on, and to make this community wiki.*</sub>

Comment: Honorable mention to [Charles Alsobrook](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/2534/charles-alsobrook)'s [avatar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AEMvt.jpg).

Comment: @Caleb haha - [even funnier when you realize that St. Nicholas actually did that.](http://www.stnicholascenter.org/pages/bishop-nicholas-loses-his-cool/)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Robin's point should be to answer the question!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: NT Wright approves.] <sup>1, 2</sup>

---

#### Footnotes:

1. The vote mechanism it one of [the most basic and important functions](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/36) of the network. It basically crowd-sources the expertise of site members to get the most useful answers at the top of the list so that users are not forced to wade through so much junk in the search of answers as happens on many forums. On this site, one of the most basic properties that make answers useful is when they show their work.<sup>3</sup>
2. See for example his treatise on [The Resurrection Son of God V3: Christian Origins and the Question of God](http://amzn.com/B00B1VG66E).
3. [N. T. Wright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N._T._Wright) is a retired Anglican bishop (Durham), former Canon Theologian of Westminster Abbey, and well known NT scholar. He is famous for being verbose<sup>4</sup>, doing his homework, and perhaps infamous as the ringleader of the [New Perspective on Paul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4706/30).
4. See also: [What are we looking for in answers?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/36)

Comment: The fact that this is not currently the highest voted meme here is disappointing to say the least. I mean, what does Darth Vader have to do with hermeneutics anyway?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Vader likes sources.]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Grumpy cat doesn't care what you feel about the text.]

Comment: this is funny, but I also think someone might object to it

Comment: @JackDouglas then they should DV it ruthlessly :P

Comment: Ezekiel 27:12 tarshish is thought to be a type of America :P

Answer (score 3):

[image: Willy Wonka isn't amused by your anachronism.]

Answer (score 3):

[image: The Rock doesn't follow your eisegesis.]

The caption helps: 'The Rock doesn't follow your eisegesis.'

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sudden clarity about the Biblical text.]<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Yes, it should be Abraham, not Moses. I had originally considered using Moses (not Noah) on a yacht with the caption, "I'm on a boat!" However, some users likely would deem this song offensive so I opted for the cheesier idea instead :)</sub>

Comment: Errm... that would be Abraham, wouldn't it? :P Or is ironic?

Comment: @Davïd also purely part of the irony. My other option was Moses (not Noah) saying, "I'm on a boat!" (i.e. the song). I probably should have stuck with just one joke/misnomer per meme, but meh

Comment: But since you mentioned it, I'll edit this to point that out ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image: I'm not sure if I should laugh or cry....]

<sub>[H/T Paul Vargas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15215170#15215170)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

**Literally living in a world of allegory**

- [The number 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_numerology): "implies 'totality of perfection,' 'completeness.'"
- [The number 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_numerology): "indicates 'imperfection,' 'man', or 'evil.'"
- [Small fry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small-fry): "of, relating to, or intended for children."

Comment: Slow clap.... That's awesome. Sadly, we get those answers here.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Can kitteh burninate tag?]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Why did they remove my (il)logical assertion of truth?]

Comment: Someone flagged this 'offensive'. If you find it offensive, please comment to say why, because I don't get it?

Comment: Keep in mind that 'lefty' simply means 'left-handed,' I'm merely taking anthropomorphic language literally as a joke. If it has another (offensive) meaning, please comment as to what it is (I can modify the meme if so, but cannot find any reason to in online searches of the word 'lefty' - the only other meaning is someone who is left-leaning politically, and we all know Jesus wasn't a conservative American Republican, either).